# Plot 3D regression surface using plot_ly

Tags: r, 3d, regression, plotly

I am trying to plot a regression model for a data set with measurements for "mue" (friction coefficient for breaking train), speed of train and temp of train. I built a simple regression model using lm so I could test plotting with plot_ly. The plot attached shows the blue markers of the original data and the surface plotted doesn't look right. It should look more like a regression surface... I also plotted in 2D to make sure the regression actually works and it does. I've posted the code below and am wondering if anyone here has any advice. Been trying everything I can find online and none of it seems to be working. I think the issue might have to do with building a grid? I've tried that a few times, but I always get error messages for vectors not matching up, etc. I'd be happy to post that as well if needed. Thank you!

**3D Regression Plot**

[image]

**2D Regression Plot**

[image]

```
set.seed(123) # randum number generator
training.samples <- avg.frame$avg.mue %>%
  createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE) # pick 80 percent of data 
train.data <- avg.frame[training.samples, ] # 80 percent is training data
test.data <- avg.frame[-training.samples, ] # 20 percent is test data

model_2 <- lm(avg.mue ~ avg.speed + avg.temp, data = train.data)
vals <- predict(model_2, train.data)

avg.mue <- matrix(vals, nrow = length(test.data$avg.speed), ncol = length(test.data$avg.temp))
plane <- avg.mue

p <- plot_ly(data = train.data, z = ~avg.mue, x = ~avg.speed, y = ~avg.temp, opacity = 0.6) %>%
  add_markers()
p %>% add_surface(z = ~plane, x = ~avg.speed, y = ~avg.temp, showscale = FALSE) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```